# Checkout Error - Street address cannot contain more than 2 lines

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, payment, address, braintree

I have hit a problem when trying to test my checkout on Magento 2.1.6.

After reading through a lot of this threads comments: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6929 and following the advice from comment linked: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6929#issuecomment-307531467

I find that the error message popping up on screen (not being logged...) is saying:

> Street address cannot contain more than 2 lines

My admin settings for customer addresses allows up to 3 lines??

I am testing this as a logged in user and have this problem. A braintree support person is also testing this and has successfully placed multiple orders into the system, but not logged in; only as a guest. So it appears to be something to do with the address of a logged in user?

Has anyone already fixed this issue who can point me to how?

Or has anyone got other ideas how to resolve please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me needed an option changing in admin. An option that was different from the system my data was migrated from... weird.

Configuration > General > State Options - make sure UK is NOT selected.
I also found a SQL insert statement that can add all the UK "states" (Counties etc) to the database, which I guess would then allow the option I deselected to be selected, thus enforcing that on UK users, and ensuring the end user cannot make a typo when entering that part of their address (it would be a select list to choose a "state" from).

Anyway, this seems to have fixed my issue, so hope this helps anyone encountering the same issue!